# Keyboard for textfield appears after second tap (time to time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfielddelegate

I have one view in my app where there is 1 text field. And I've noticed that keyboard appears after second tap.

But it's interesting that on iPhone it's time to time (some time appears after first tap at once, and some time after second tap only).
On iPad looks like it more ofter appears after second tap only.

- I use `UITextFieldDelegate`
- in `viewDidLoad` I assign the delegate `_locationTextField.delegate = self;`
- and I use delegate methods `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, `textFieldDidEndEditing`, `textFieldShouldReturn`

e.g.:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    _locationNameBeforeManualEdit = _locationTextField.text;
    // save the previod city value to compare after did end editing
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing");

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self continueButtonPressed:nil];
    // [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

in storyboard
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you implement other methods from `UITextFieldDelegate`? Are your methods executed?

Comment: if you using Storyboard?

Comment: In console I see that all 3 methods are executed. Only these 3 methods (mentioned above) are in the code. No events handled from storyboard.

Comment: looks like it more related to iPad - keyboard appears on it even after 3rd/4th tap. On iPhone keyboard appears usually at once, and rarely after second tap.
Can't figure out that could be the reason )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here on Stackoverflow - solution related with keyboard preload:

```
- (void)preloadKeyboard {
    UITextField *lagFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:lagFreeField];
    [lagFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
    [lagFreeField resignFirstResponder];
    [lagFreeField removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

This method should be used in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of `AppDelegate`.